# Wanting to round off div element

Tags: html

I was wondering how I could round off the edges on this?

```html
<div style="background-color: yellow; border: 2px solid red; margin: 4px; padding: 2px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
<h2>This site is not yet finished!</h2>
</div>
```

Thanks, Jeremy.

Comment: please tell me you did try googling this....I need more faith in humanity

Comment: I did but all tutorials didn't achieve what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use **border-radius** Example:

```
border-radius:10px;
```

```html
<div style="background-color: yellow; border: 2px solid red; margin: 4px; padding: 2px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-radius:10px;">
<h2>This site is not yet finished!</h2>
</div>
```